# How to inject into Gradle Unit Test Scope (Android, Dagger)

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, dagger

I am using the new unit testing feature in the Gradle 1.1 Android plugin. Let's say I have a JUnit Test like this:

```
public class GlossaryItemJsonTest {
    @Inject
    Gson gson; //this is not getting injected, so it's null


    @Test
    public void testDeserialization() throws Exception {
        //...
    }
}
```

How can I inject from my `main` scope into my `test` scope? I do not want to duplicate any code from my main `DataModule`. Traditionally I would add an `injects=GsonTest.class` field to the `@Module` annotation, but the main `DataModule` cannot see any classes from the `test` scope.

```
@Module(
        injects  = GsonTest.class //does not compile
        complete = false,
        library  = true
)
public class DataModule {
    @Provides @Singleton provideGson(){...}
}
```

How do inject my `gson` variable in the Gradle `test` scope?